# Car doesn't start

Tags: starting

My Honda crv 2008 model just went off while driving and it doesn't start anymore. It doesn't show up the oil, battery and key light anymore. The diagnosing machine doesn't pick up any fault and we have also tried different batteries but still nothing. The cambelt is OK and the fuses too. Petrol pump, computer box 100%. What might be the problem.?

Comment: Not saying it is but It could still be the ecm even tho its connecting and not showing any codes. Its actually pretty typical of honda ecm's that go bad that they do not show CEL and 0  DTC's.

Comment: First thing to check would be for dirty or bad battery cables. I believe there also may be an inline fuselink in one of the cables.